# How would one relay (pass) a paramarray argument received by one function onto a second function in vba?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, paramarray

In VBA, there are times when you might want to pass an indeterminant number of arguments onto a function.  In the VB world, paramarray handles such.  But what if one needs, in turn to pass such onto a sub-function?

In the challenge here, I have a couple of different places that format a string, inserting subsequent values, for example:

`tx = SetSQL("UPDATE tabA SET cd={1} WHERE id={2}", "'123'", 89)`

Depending upon the situation, there might be 1 or *n* parameters.

This worked well when I handled all the SQL directly.  For example:

`set rsNEW = currentdb.execute (SetSQL("UPDATE tabA SET cd={1} WHERE id={2}", "'123'", 89))`

But, I then found that I had several situations where the same processing was repeated and I wanted to refactor some of that into a more all encompassing call some of the time.  I wanted to wrap the `SetSQL` inside of another routine.  For example:

`public sub DoMyDBThing("UPDATE tabA SET cd={1} WHERE id={2}", "'123'", 89)`

And this put me in a situation where I needed to transfer a `paramarray` to a `paramarray` .

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write a wrapper function that converts the paramarray to an array variant.

As I already used `SetSQL`, it remained accepting the `paramarray`.  And what it once did became `SetSQLBase`.  In this way, my other extensions that needed the same functionality could also take paramarrays and then use `SetSQLBase` to generate the text. This way I didn't have to replicate the program.

Hence:

```
Dim v() As Variant
  v = p
  SetSQL = SetSQLBase(sql, v())

End Function
```

This still handles the *n* number of trailing parameters as it rewraps the `paramarray` as `variant array` to pass to the core routine:

```
Dim ct As Long
Dim tx As String
  
  While InStr(1, sql, "{") > 0 And ct < 8
    On Error Resume Next
    tx = IIf(ct > UBound(p), "", p(ct))
    On Error GoTo 0
    ct = ct + 1
    
    sql = Replace(sql, "{" & ct & "}", tx)
  Wend
  
  SetSQLBase = sql
End Function
```

Now other routines can also call the same thing, also accepting an unknown number of arguments, get the sql back and process.  For example:

```
Private Function PassTag_RunSQL(ByRef ds As clsSideXDB, cdStep As String, sql As String, ParamArray p() As Variant) As Boolean

Dim v() As Variant

  v = p
  PassTag_RunSQL = True
  sql = SetSQLBase(sql, v)
  ...
```